# Is it possible to start console process from ruby GUI script (.rbw)

Tags: ruby, windows, tk-toolkit

I have a GUI Ruby tool that needs to spawn a child command-line process, for example ping. If i do this on Windows, the console window will appear and dissapear for console process, that is very annoying. Is it possible to start a process from GUI Ruby script with no console window visible? If i use backtick operator or `Kernel#system`, the console window will appear, see example below:

```
require 'Tk'
require 'thread'
Thread.new { `ping 8.8.8.8` }
TkRoot.new.mainloop
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that every executable on Windows is defined to be either a GUI executable or a Console executable (well, there's more detail than that but it doesn't matter here) at the time it is built. The executable that's running your Ruby script is a GUI executable (it also happens to use Tk to actually build a GUI, even if only a very simple one in your screenshot) and the ping executable is a Console executable. If a GUI executable starts a Console executable, a console is *automatically* created to run the executable in; **you *can't* change this**.

Of course, the picture is more complex than that. That's because a console application can actually work with the GUI (it just needs to do the right API calls) and you can use a whole catalogue of tricks to cause the console window to stay out of the way (such as starting ping through an appropriately-configured shortcut file) but such things are rather awkward. The easiest way is to have the console window be there the whole time by making Ruby itself be a console app (through [naming your script with the `.rb` suffix, not `.rbw`](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/05/faq-scriptrb-versus-scriptrbw.html)). Yes, it doesn't really get rid of the problem, but it stops any annoying flashing.

If you were using ping as the purpose of your app (i.e., to find out if services were up) then I'd as whether it is possible/advisable to switch to writing the checking code directly in Ruby by connecting to the service instead of pinging it, as ping just measures whether the target OS kernel is alive, and not the service executable. This is a fine distinction, but I've seen machines get into a state where no executables were running but the machine was still responding to pings; this was *very* strange and can totally break your mental abstractions but can happen. But since you're only using ping as an example, I think you can just focus on the (rather problematic) console handling. Still, if you can do it without running a subprocess then definitely choose that method (on Windows; if you were on any sort of Unix you wouldn't have this problem at all).

Comment: The “tl;dr” version: it's a Windows problem, not a Ruby problem.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer. I know about console subsystem flag in portable executable format and was hoping that it's some trick available in Ruby to handle this, for example CreateProcess with STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW and SW_HIDE :). It seems i will need to use Win32API Ruby library and call CreateProcess manually O_O.

Comment: @EyeofHell: That would work, but I don't encourage doing deep hacking if you don't _need_ it. You probably want to read http://rubyforge.org/docman/view.php/85/1720/Process.html

Comment: I need to run subversion in background on multiple platforms, for end users. Installing ruby / python SVN bindings will be hell and definitely impossible for end users :)

Comment: @Eye: Being a SVN client's quite possible to do as a library.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to spawn processes with Ruby. Here is a [couple of ways to do it](http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/). I am not sure what you mean with

> the console window will appear and dissapear for console process

but I think the best way for you to do it is to simply grab out and err and show it to your user in your own window. If you want the native windows console to appear wou probably need to something fancy with windows scripting.

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep a spawned console alive is to have it run a batch file with a `PAUSE` command at the end:

rungping.bat:

```
ping %1
pause
exit
```

In your ruby file:

```
Thread.new {`start runping.bat 8.8.8.8`}
```